# creating form instance from c# application issue?

Tags: c#

I have created and used an instance of form application inside my program.
But the problem I faced is the following form is won't be created. What is the problem please help me?

The error message generated when starting debug:

> Error 1   'Face_Recognition.frm_faceReg' does not contain a constructor
>   that takes 0 arguments

the snapshot of the code I used to create an instance of the form:

[image]

**The Actual code of frm_faceReg form is:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.CV.CvEnum;

using System.IO;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Xml;
using System.Threading;


namespace Face_Recognition
{
    public partial class frm_faceReg : Form
    {
        #region Variables
        //Camera specific
        Capture grabber;

        //Images for finding face
        Image<Bgr, Byte> currentFrame;
        Image<Gray, byte> result = null;
        Image<Gray, byte> gray_frame = null;

        //Classifier
        CascadeClassifier Face;

        //For aquiring 10 images in a row
        List<Image<Gray, byte>> resultImages = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();
        int results_list_pos = 0;
        int num_faces_to_aquire = 10;
        bool RECORD = false;

        //Saving Jpg
        List<Image<Gray, byte>> ImagestoWrite = new List<Image<Gray, byte>>();
        EncoderParameters ENC_Parameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        EncoderParameter ENC = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100);
        ImageCodecInfo Image_Encoder_JPG;

        //Saving XAML Data file
        List<string> NamestoWrite = new List<string>();
        List<string> NamesforFile = new List<string>();
        XmlDocument docu = new XmlDocument();

        //Variables
        frm_faceDec_faceRec Parent;
        #endregion

        public frm_faceReg(frm_faceDec_faceRec _Parent)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Parent = _Parent;
            Face = Parent.Face;
            //Face = new HaarCascade(Application.StartupPath + "/Cascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml");
            ENC_Parameters.Param[0] = ENC;
            Image_Encoder_JPG = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            initialise_capture();
        }

        private void Training_Form_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            stop_capture();
            Parent.retrain();
            Parent.initialise_capture();
        }

        //Camera Start Stop
        public void initialise_capture()
        {
            grabber = new Capture();
            grabber.QueryFrame();
            //Initialize the FrameGraber event
            Application.Idle += new EventHandler(FrameGrabber);
        }
        private void stop_capture()
        {
            Application.Idle -= new EventHandler(FrameGrabber);
            if (grabber != null)
            {
                grabber.Dispose();
            }
            //Initialize the FrameGraber event
        }

        //Process Frame
        void FrameGrabber(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Get the current frame form capture device
            currentFrame = grabber.QueryFrame().Resize(320, 240, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);

            //Convert it to Grayscale
            if (currentFrame != null)
            {
                gray_frame = currentFrame.Convert<Gray, Byte>();

                //Face Detector
                //MCvAvgComp[][] facesDetected = gray_frame.DetectHaarCascade(Face, 1.2, 10, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.HAAR_DETECTION_TYPE.DO_CANNY_PRUNING, new Size(20, 20)); //old method
                Rectangle[] facesDetected = Face.DetectMultiScale(gray_frame, 1.2, 10, new Size(50, 50), Size.Empty);

                //Action for each element detected
                for(int i = 0; i< facesDetected.Length; i++)// (Rectangle face_found in facesDetected)
                {
                    //This will focus in on the face from the haar results its not perfect but it will remove a majoriy
                    //of the background noise
                    facesDetected[i].X += (int)(facesDetected[i].Height * 0.15);
                    facesDetected[i].Y += (int)(facesDetected[i].Width * 0.22);
                    facesDetected[i].Height -= (int)(facesDetected[i].Height * 0.3);
                    facesDetected[i].Width -= (int)(facesDetected[i].Width * 0.35);

                    result = currentFrame.Copy(facesDetected[i]).Convert<Gray, byte>().Resize(100, 100, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.INTER.CV_INTER_CUBIC);
                    result._EqualizeHist();
                    face_PICBX.Image = result.ToBitmap();
                    //draw the face detected in the 0th (gray) channel with blue color
                    currentFrame.Draw(facesDetected[i], new Bgr(Color.Red), 2);

                }
                if (RECORD && facesDetected.Length > 0 && resultImages.Count < num_faces_to_aquire)
                {
                    resultImages.Add(result);
                    count_lbl.Text = "Count: " + resultImages.Count.ToString();
                    if (resultImages.Count == num_faces_to_aquire)
                    {
                        ADD_BTN.Enabled = true;
                        NEXT_BTN.Visible = true;
                        PREV_btn.Visible = true;
                        count_lbl.Visible = false;
                        Single_btn.Visible = true;
                        ADD_ALL.Visible = true;
                        RECORD = false;
                        Application.Idle -= new EventHandler(FrameGrabber);
                    }
                }

                image_PICBX.Image = currentFrame.ToBitmap();
            }
        }

        //Saving The Data
        private bool save_training_data(Image face_data)
        {
            try
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                bool file_create = true;
                string facename = "face_" + NAME_PERSON.Text + "_" + rand.Next().ToString() + ".jpg";
                while (file_create)
                {

                    if (!File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/" + facename))
                    {
                        file_create = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        facename = "face_" + NAME_PERSON.Text + "_" + rand.Next().ToString() + ".jpg";
                    }
                }


                if(Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/"))
                {
                    face_data.Save(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/" + facename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
                else
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/");
                    face_data.Save(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/" + facename, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                }
                if (File.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/TrainedLabels.xml"))
                {
                    //File.AppendAllText(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/TrainedLabels.txt", NAME_PERSON.Text + "\n\r");
                    bool loading = true;
                    while (loading)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            docu.Load(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/TrainedLabels.xml");
                            loading = false;
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            docu = null;
                            docu = new XmlDocument();
                            Thread.Sleep(10);
                        }
                    }

                    //Get the root element
                    XmlElement root = docu.DocumentElement;

                    XmlElement face_D = docu.CreateElement("FACE");
                    XmlElement name_D = docu.CreateElement("NAME");
                    XmlElement file_D = docu.CreateElement("FILE");

                    //Add the values for each nodes
                    //name.Value = textBoxName.Text;
                    //age.InnerText = textBoxAge.Text;
                    //gender.InnerText = textBoxGender.Text;
                    name_D.InnerText = NAME_PERSON.Text;
                    file_D.InnerText = facename;

                    //Construct the Person element
                    //person.Attributes.Append(name);
                    face_D.AppendChild(name_D);
                    face_D.AppendChild(file_D);

                    //Add the New person element to the end of the root element
                    root.AppendChild(face_D);

                    //Save the document
                    docu.Save(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/TrainedLabels.xml");
                    //XmlElement child_element = docu.CreateElement("FACE");
                    //docu.AppendChild(child_element);
                    //docu.Save("TrainedLabels.xml");
                }
                else
                {
                    FileStream FS_Face = File.OpenWrite(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/TrainedLabels.xml");
                    using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FS_Face))
                    {
                        writer.WriteStartDocument();
                        writer.WriteStartElement("Faces_For_Training");

                        writer.WriteStartElement("FACE");
                        writer.WriteElementString("NAME", NAME_PERSON.Text);
                        writer.WriteElementString("FILE", facename);
                        writer.WriteEndElement();

                        writer.WriteEndElement();
                        writer.WriteEndDocument();
                    }
                    FS_Face.Close();
                }

                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }

        }
        private ImageCodecInfo GetEncoder(ImageFormat format)
        {
            ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
            foreach (ImageCodecInfo codec in codecs)
            {
                if (codec.FormatID == format.Guid)
                {
                    return codec;
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        //Delete all the old training data by simply deleting the folder
        private void Delete_Data_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/"))
            {
                Directory.Delete(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/", true);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(Application.StartupPath + "/TrainedFaces/");
            }
        }

        //Add the image to training data
        private void ADD_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (resultImages.Count == num_faces_to_aquire)
            {
                if (!save_training_data(face_PICBX.Image)) MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error in saving file info. Training data not saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                stop_capture();
                if (!save_training_data(face_PICBX.Image)) MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error in saving file info. Training data not saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                initialise_capture();
            }
        }
        private void Single_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RECORD = false;
            resultImages.Clear();
            NEXT_BTN.Visible = false;
            PREV_btn.Visible = false;
            Application.Idle += new EventHandler(FrameGrabber);
            Single_btn.Visible = false;
            count_lbl.Text = "Count: 0";
            count_lbl.Visible = true;
        }
        //Get 10 image to train
        private void RECORD_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (RECORD)
            {
                RECORD = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (resultImages.Count == 10)
                {
                    resultImages.Clear();
                    Application.Idle += new EventHandler(FrameGrabber);
                }
                RECORD = true;
                ADD_BTN.Enabled = false;
            }

        }
        private void NEXT_BTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (results_list_pos < resultImages.Count - 1)
            {
                face_PICBX.Image = resultImages[results_list_pos].ToBitmap();
                results_list_pos++;
                PREV_btn.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                NEXT_BTN.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        private void PREV_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (results_list_pos > 0)
            {
                results_list_pos--;
                face_PICBX.Image = resultImages[results_list_pos].ToBitmap();
                NEXT_BTN.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                PREV_btn.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        private void ADD_ALL_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i<resultImages.Count;i++)
            {
                face_PICBX.Image = resultImages[i].ToBitmap();
                if (!save_training_data(face_PICBX.Image)) MessageBox.Show("Error", "Error in saving file info. Training data not saved", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
            ADD_ALL.Visible = false;
            //restart single face detection
            Single_btn_Click(null, null);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
            this.Dispose();
        }

        private void frm_faceReg_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Error seems pretty clear to me. Look at the constructor for `Face_Recognition.frm_faceReg`, clearly it needs you to pass it something.

Comment: Please include the actual code (and not just screenshots).  Also the code for `frm_faceReg` would be nice to see.

Comment: I sent the code. Thanks.

Comment: See my answer. Case closed :-)

Answer (score 1):

Well, obviously the form doesn't declare a parameterless constructor - just as the error message says. All constructors expect parameters to be passed to them, or the constructors aren't accessible*.

Check the constructors of `frm_faceReg` for possible values you need to pass.

*) for example if there is a factory method you need to call instead of using `new` with a constructor, but that's a rare case.

---

The code you added makes pretty clear that there's only one constructor defined that expects one parameter:

```
public frm_faceReg(frm_faceDec_faceRec _Parent)
```

You need to pass an instance of `frm_faceDec_faceRec`, whatever that is.

And as a side note: You should really be reading about naming conventions in C#...

Comment: I'd mention that the empty constructor is autogenerated when there are no other constructors defined.

Comment: Why? This doesn't add to the solution of the problem. The error says there's no parameterless constructor, so it's pretty clear that there's either only private constructors or public constructors that expect parameters.

Comment: I'm suggesting an alternate way to fix the problem by manually defining the default constructor.  This sometime throws people off because it is often autogenerated.

Comment: Well, what if the form *requires* information to be passed in from the caller? Then adding a parameterless constructor would break things. Not every form is an island...

Comment: That's true.  It's a _possible_ solution.  Often you can get around this but using an object initializer (with the `{}`)

Comment: But even with the object initializer, setting the property is still *optional*. In the code the OP posted it is clear that the form *can not work* without an instance of the required class `frm_faceDec_faceRec`.

Comment: Didn't notice the edit with the actual code.  Yes in this case it would make no sense to use a default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

This means that the object's constructor has parameters.

```
frm_faceReg frg = new frm_faceReg(PUT SOME ARGS HERE);
```